# Can't use [] for reading HTTP500 error

Tags: php, http

I'm getting a http500 error with this code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = ["charlestdjames1@gmail.com"];
    $subject = $_POST["name"];
    $message = $_POST["content"];
    $headers = $_POST["email"];

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}   
?>
```

the logs state that I cannot use [] for reading, I'm not sure if this is a error with the code or not.

The form I'm using:

```
<form method="post">
            <span class="close">x</span>
            <label class="modalFont" for="name">Name:</label>
            <input class="modalFont" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Please enter your name" /><br />
            <label class="modalFont" for="email">Email Address:</label>
            <input class="modalFont" type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Please enter your email" /><br />
            <label class="modalFont" for="message">Message:</label>
            <input class="modalFont" type="text" id="message" name="content" placeholder="Enter your message here" /><br />

            <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using. Short array syntax wasn't added till 5.4 (iirc).

Comment: to should be `$to = "charlestdjames1@gmail.com";`

Comment: I was running 5.3, switched to 5.4. Thanks! Now I just need to find a solution to nothing but a blank screen coming up.

Comment: Got that too, missing a ; at the end of the if statement. Oh the joys of finding trivial syntax errors. Thanks again for the help!